# Why doesn't my listview show expected result in my android app?

Tags: android, listview

When I use listview in my app, I want to use `this.setSelection(0);` to skip to the first item but everytime I do this the foto with the girl in the attached picture shakes. This is not very smooth and I don't know how to solve this.

If I use this `this.smoothScrollToPosition(0);` the girl doesn't shake but the top menu shakes. 
Here is the picture. Thanks for your replies!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `setSelectionAfterHeaderView()`?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionAfterHeaderView%28%29

Comment: I have tried this but another problem occurs. thanks